# Grouped methods in class UML produced by Doxygen have duplicates with asterisks

Tags: c++, uml, doxygen, dot

I try to generate UML in html documentation for the following class using doxygen/dot.

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    /**
     * @name My Grouping
     *
     * description
     */
    // @{
    void methodA();
    void methodB();
    // @}
};
```

I specifically want to use grouping as described [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html). But when I do so I get a UML diagram with 2 entries for each method, one of which has an asterisk in front:

[image: see image]

Essentially I would like to remove the entries with the asterisks, but still do the grouping. Does anyone know how to do this?

I am using doxygen 1.8.11 on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.
My Doxyfile is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14-KgvY5Ig6wr7A0o_zAwtFKlUA0dXXum).

Comment: I have no idea why the methods are listed twice (from the conceptual point of view it is clear from the code), but it is done from the beginning (1.8.1) the UML diagram is supported. probably best to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: I'm still having similar problems. I have added this issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7197